# User Input saved to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-sqlite

I'm extremely new to Android Development and I'm decent at Java. I'm working currently on making my first app and I'm stuck at a spot where I've researched for the past two days but I just don't know what to do. I want to make something similar to how Contacts is set up in Android.

I was able to create two buttons in the main activity page and have an intent to another activity by the click of the button(s). But when I come to the 2nd activity, I want the user to be able to "Add Class" and I want to take this to a new activity where the user inputs information such as "Class Name" "Assignment Type" "Assignment Worth" etc. and then hit save. And by doing so, I want this New Class added to the activity with the listview item "Add Class".

But then I want the user to be able to click the new item created, for example, "Math" and when he/she presses it, it opens a new activity with the information stored previously. And I was wondering how I go about that.
Thank You.

Comment: start with tutorials http://developer.android.com/training/index.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to save the user's input data to persistent storage, eg: shared preferences, sqlite data base or plain text file, I would go with a sqlite data base as it's the most suited for this job. After the user saves his data he'll return to the first activity in which you pull all data from the sqlite data base and load it in the listview via CursorLoader and LoaderManager, as this will load the data into the listview asynchronously.

I don't know your level of skill but I suggest start to learn about android's sqlite, good tutorials can be found on youtube, like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v61A90qlK9s) and for CursorLoaders [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-njNGMhPCU).